# How to make a shiny pinger website more interactive

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following RShiny website that pings some hosts and show their status and an average latency time.
Code works well but I am trying to improve a couple things:

- I would like to see the device status (green or red marks) as their occur and not when the entire code finishes
- I have noticed that the Refresh button doesn't do anything. I expect this to restart the ping process

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(pingr)
library(shinycssloaders)


# Define UI for application that pings devices
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Load Font Awesome from CDN
  tags$head(
    tags$link(
      rel = "stylesheet",
      href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    ),
    

  ),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Device Status Checker"),
  
  # Devices Status Section
  fluidRow(
    column(4, 
           h4("Devices Status"),
           uiOutput("devices_status")
    ),
    column(8, 
           h4("Devices Response Time"),
           dataTableOutput("devices_response_time")
    )
  ),
  
  # Refresh Button
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           actionButton("refresh_button", "Refresh")
    )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(pingr)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)



# Define server logic for application that pings devices
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # List of devices to ping
  devices_list <- c("www.google.com"
                    ,"www.amazon.com"
  )
  
  
  
  # Ping Devices function
  ping_devices <- function() {
    
    
    # Create empty vectors to store device status and response time
    status <- vector("character", length(devices_list))
    response_time <- vector("numeric", length(devices_list))
    
    # Loop through devices and ping them
    for (i in seq_along(devices_list)) {
      ping_result <- ping_port(devices_list[i]
                               , 80L
                               , timeout = 0.3
                               )
      if (all(is.na(ping_result))) {
        status[i] <- "red"
        response_time[i] <- NA
      } else {
        status[i] <- "green"
        response_time[i] <- ping_result
      }
    }
    
    # Create data frame of device status and response time
    devices_df <- data.frame(Device = devices_list,
                             Status = status,
                             ResponseTime = response_time)

    return(devices_df)
  }
  
  # Initial ping of devices
  devices_df <- ping_devices()

    
  # Render device status icons
  output$devices_status <- renderUI({
    
    
      devices_status <- lapply(devices_df$Status, function(x) {
        if (x == "green") {
          tags$i(class = "fa fa-check-circle", style = "color: green;")
        } else {
          tags$i(class = "fa fa-times-circle", style = "color: red;")
        }
      })
      devices_status <- mapply(function(icon, device) {
        paste(icon, device, sep = " ")
      }, devices_status, devices_df$Device, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
      HTML(paste(devices_status, collapse = "<br>"))
    })
  
  # Render device response time table
  output$devices_response_time <- renderDataTable({
    devices_df$ResponseTime <- round(devices_df$ResponseTime, 2)
    devices_df 
  })
  
  # Refresh button action
  observeEvent(input$refresh_button, {
    devices_df <<- ping_devices()
  })
  
}
```